# How do you get a selected value from gridview dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, gridview, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

i have a gridview which has one of the columns as a dropdown. When the user selects a different drop down option i would like to get the selected value. How do i go about this? Please see code below. This code seems to work in IE9  and Firefox but does not work in IE8.  In IE8 i get the following error "options.selectedIndex' is null or not an object" .

```
     var gridview =  document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grvTrainHistoryCapture');

     if (selectedRowIndex == null) return;
     var statusCell = gridview.rows[parseInt(selectedRowIndex)+ 1].cells[5];
     var ddlStatus = statusCell.childNodes[1];

     var statusID = ddlStatus.options[ddlStatus.options.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I HAVE TESTED THIS CODE UNDER IE8, AND IT WORKS AS IT SHOULD.
i guess the problem is the object you are passing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    var e = document.getElementById('test');
    alert(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value );
</script>
```

Comment: i see my comment about "check what you are passing as e" was deleted.... the code i have posted 100% works.
so the only thing left is to check what you are passing to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function ShowDropDownValueInGridView(vIndex) {
        //Assume you are passing in the Row Index and your dropdown control is in a Template in cell 2
        Gridview1 = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>');
        var cell = Gridview1.rows[vIndex].cells[2]
        var dropdownSelectedValue = cell.childNodes[0].value;
        alert(dropdownSelectedValue);
    }
```